# jQuery: Animated Meters

Tags: jquery, animation

I've a slight problem with jQuery animation.  First I'll provide my code:

```
<div id="xp_container">
  <div id="xp_bar_container">
    <div id="xp_bar_filler" style="width:0%;">
      <div id="xp_bar_text">
        <div id="user_xp">XP: 0 / 100</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="user_level">
    Level 1
  </div>
  <br style="clear:both;">
</div>

//CSS

#xp_container
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:3px;
  right:5px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:14px;
}

#xp_bar_container
{
  float:right;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:18px;
  width:200px;
  background:black;
  text-align:left;
}

#xp_bar_filler
{
  background:green url('images/meter_fill.png');
  height:18px;
}

#xp_bar_text
{
  width:200px;
  height:18px;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:white;
}

#user_xp
{
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
  left:10px;
}

#user_level
{
  float:right;
  margin-right:15px;
}
```

This code makes a filling 'meter' for certain stats in a game of mine, this one specifically for a user's experience.  I wanted to add a nice animation feature that would fill the meter from its current width to another width.  I've done this successfully.

My Problem:

I need to adjust `#xp_bar_filler`, which contains another `<div>` that holds the text (displaying their experience in the bar).  When I animate the meter to fill, it also sets the text `<div> (#xp_bar_text)` to the specified width.  `#xp_bar_text` needs to be at width `100%` at all times during animation, with only `#xp_bar_filler` changing width.  Can anyone advise as to what to do here?  I am using a simple `animate(width:100%)` for testing.

Comment: Personally, i'd use the jQuery ui progressbar. http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Comment: there's isn't any js in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:visible !important;` to `#xp_bar_filler`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/RtkQv/

Comment: Thank you my friend!  Don't think the others quite got what I was after, but you certainly did.

Comment: @Phillip if it solved your question, feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Gotta wait a minute, but I will!

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider use jQuery UI? Theres a nice plugin called `progressbar`, that fits your need. Check it out here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated